# @PathVariable doesn't work for only one of the mappings

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, mapping, path-variables

Hi everyone I usually use `@PathVariable`, but for this case, I don't know why it doesn't work.

**menu.jsp**:

```
<a href="<c:url value= '/admin/myCart/1/${idproducts}' />">Panier</a>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/viewProduct/{ref}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getProduit(@PathVariable("ref") int ref, Model model) {
**model.addAttribute("idproducts",this.orderedProductService.getIdOrderedProductsByclient(1));**
model.addAttribute("produit", this.produitService.getProduitById(ref));


    return "menu";
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/admin/monPanier/{idproducts}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myCart( @PathVariable("idproducts") String idproducts,Model model) {
     return mycart;
}
```

So **menu.jsp** get `{idproducts}` (which is a String containing ids separated by " / ", for example: idproducts = 5/6/7), but I don't know why `@PathVariable("idproducts")` doesn't work. The error is:

> **No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVCHibernate/admin/myCart/5/6/7/]**

Comment: Does one product has granted id which is string "5/6/7"? Or do you try to get cart that contains three products with ids 5, 6 and 7?

Answer (score 0):

You have URL defined as,

```
/admin/mycart/1/**${idproducts}**
```

But in `controller` there is no such mapping defined with `/admin/mycart/1`

It is defined to be with `/admin/mycart`,

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/admin/mycart/{idproducts}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String monPanier( @PathVariable("idproducts") String idproducts,Model model) {
     return mycart;
}
```

So try to fix your `controller` as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/admin/mycart/1/{idproducts}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String monPanier( @PathVariable("idproducts") String idproducts,Model model) {
         return mycart;
}
```

Comment: Ouups.. Sorry it's just problem of translation, because my code is in frensh. Now i edited everything in english. Now can you please check if you can see the source of this error ?

Comment: @SalimLyoussi check my updated answer. You need to define /1 in your request mapping on controller method. If /1 is dynamic then you need to define multiple path variables.